# Restore Ruby gems after OS High Sierra upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, heroku

I just upgraded my OS to High Sierra and my Rails application on Heroku stopped working with the following error:

```
   -----> Ruby app detected
   -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
   -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.2
   -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
          Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.0). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
          Using rake 12.3.0
          Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
          Using minitest 5.10.3
          Using thread_safe 0.3.6
          Using builder 3.2.3
          Using erubis 2.7.0
          Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
          Using crass 1.0.3
          Using rack 1.6.8
          Using mini_mime 1.0.0
          Using arel 6.0.4
          Using execjs 2.7.0
          Using bcrypt 3.1.11
          Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
          Using ffi 1.9.18
          Using bundler 1.15.2
          Using thor 0.20.0
          Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
          Using colored 1.2
          Using multi_json 1.12.2
          Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
          Using json 1.8.6
          Using nprogress-rails 0.2.0.2
          Using pg 0.21.0
          Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
          Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
          Using rdoc 4.3.0
          Using tilt 2.0.8
          Using unicode_utils 1.4.0
          Using i18n 0.9.1
          Using tzinfo 1.2.4
          Using nokogiri 1.8.1
          Using mail 2.7.0
          Using autoprefixer-rails 7.1.6
          Using uglifier 3.2.0
          Using rack-test 0.6.3
          Using sprockets 3.7.1
          Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
          Using coffee-script 2.4.1
          Using select2-rails 4.0.3
          Using turbolinks 5.0.1
          Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
          Using activesupport 4.2.8
          Using sdoc 0.4.2
          Using loofah 2.1.1
          Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
          Using globalid 0.4.1
          Using activemodel 4.2.8
          Using jbuilder 2.7.0
          Using sass-listen 4.0.0
          Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
          Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
          Using activerecord 4.2.8
          Using sass 3.5.3
          Using activejob 4.2.8
          Using actionview 4.2.8
          Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
          Using actionpack 4.2.8
          Using actionmailer 4.2.8
          Using railties 4.2.8
          Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
          Using chart-js-rails 0.1.4
          Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
          Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
          Using jquery-turbolinks 2.1.0
          Using rails 4.2.8
          Using responders 2.4.0
          Using sass-rails 5.0.7
          Using tabulous 2.1.4
          Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 69 gems now installed.
          Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
          Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
          Bundle completed (1.05s)
          Cleaning up the bundler cache.
          Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.0). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
   -----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
          Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
   ###### WARNING:
          Removing `vendor/bundle`.
          Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
          and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
          `bundle pack` instead.
   ###### WARNING:
          No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
          We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
   -----> Discovering process types
          Procfile declares types     -> (none)
          Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
   -----> Compressing...
          Done: 482M
   -----> Launching...
    !     Warning: Your slug size exceeds our soft limit (482 MB) which may affect boot time.
          Released v46
          https://nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I installed gems using rbenv and set global and local to the latest version 2.4.2. 
I "bundle updated" the gems in this app but I am not sure what went wrong during the OS upgrade...

The app actually works fine on my localhost but just not on Heroku. I pushed my app from github using Heroku's manual deploy function, of which the result (error) is shown above.

Edit: I ran `heroku logs --app nameless-headland-25042` and the following is the log. `git push heroku master` results in successful build and the app runs normally on may local server too. 'heroku restart' and 'heroku run rails console' run okay but the app still crashes with H10 error.

```
2017-11-22T19:09:53.481580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-22T19:09:58.598103+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `ruby -v` by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:10:01.298088+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `ruby -v` by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:10:17.627615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 26537 -e production`
2017-11-22T19:10:20.294752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211680+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:486:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211722+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:461:in `validate_runtime!'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211743+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211729+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211723+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.211742+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2017-11-22T19:10:20.310479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-22T19:10:21.822127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=5ca8def8-6d30-43cc-9a37-b61e0569aff9 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:10:22.087967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=3e1132da-cfc1-4106-b1d1-c8813d0d92c8 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:10:26.078493+00:00 heroku[run.7220]: Awaiting client
2017-11-22T19:10:26.040233+00:00 heroku[run.7220]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-22T19:10:26.776223+00:00 heroku[run.8213]: Awaiting client
2017-11-22T19:10:26.973557+00:00 heroku[run.8213]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-22T19:10:50.018572+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:10:56.080177+00:00 heroku[run.7220]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2017-11-22T19:10:56.082673+00:00 heroku[run.7220]: Process exited with status 128
2017-11-22T19:10:56.099492+00:00 heroku[run.7220]: State changed from up to complete
2017-11-22T19:10:56.777794+00:00 heroku[run.8213]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2017-11-22T19:10:56.781655+00:00 heroku[run.8213]: Process exited with status 128
2017-11-22T19:10:56.796121+00:00 heroku[run.8213]: State changed from up to complete
2017-11-22T19:11:15.476237+00:00 heroku[run.3078]: Awaiting client
2017-11-22T19:11:15.669289+00:00 heroku[run.3078]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-22T19:11:18.149746+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:11:42.403048+00:00 heroku[run.2308]: Awaiting client
2017-11-22T19:11:42.448759+00:00 heroku[run.2308]: Starting process with command `bash`
2017-11-22T19:11:42.504773+00:00 heroku[run.2308]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-22T19:11:45.477512+00:00 heroku[run.3078]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2017-11-22T19:11:45.480343+00:00 heroku[run.3078]: Process exited with status 128
2017-11-22T19:11:45.492467+00:00 heroku[run.3078]: State changed from up to complete
2017-11-22T19:13:02.638906+00:00 heroku[run.2308]: State changed from up to complete
2017-11-22T19:13:02.626226+00:00 heroku[run.2308]: Process exited with status 130
2017-11-22T19:14:35.403208+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:14:58.752336+00:00 heroku[run.4399]: Starting process with command `bash`
2017-11-22T19:14:58.728051+00:00 heroku[run.4399]: Awaiting client
2017-11-22T19:14:58.920165+00:00 heroku[run.4399]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-22T19:15:38.245463+00:00 heroku[run.4399]: State changed from up to complete
2017-11-22T19:15:38.233115+00:00 heroku[run.4399]: Process exited with status 127
2017-11-22T19:24:05.273542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=37071eae-5041-4eab-b125-3d5dbda9dee9 fwd="209.171.88.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:24:05.675915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=cbffabff-23ab-43b7-bab8-3d124d354853 fwd="209.171.88.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:26:48.235036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=www.trialn.com request_id=93f709b3-dc4a-496e-875b-ea9f3bc4b8d8 fwd="138.246.253.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:29:29.248613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=e1ce9f53-b509-452b-a9f4-dfe0459d32b0 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:29:29.514570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=c1bf8800-8496-42e5-8856-e14210a09ec9 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:37:05.406000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=fdfb412c-f52a-469d-80fd-7b286adb005b fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:37:05.746892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=369e49b2-bfd5-42fb-a3bd-52a6cdabeebb fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:56:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:56:44.065170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-22T19:56:43.831102+00:00 app[api]: Release v66 created by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:56:43.831102+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 10ec53f8 by user sampbay@outlook.com
2017-11-22T19:56:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-11-22T19:56:55.109511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 26954 -e production`
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043796+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:486:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043819+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:461:in `validate_runtime!'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043821+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043849+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.043853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2017-11-22T19:56:57.119277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-22T19:56:57.131451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-22T19:56:57.133421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-22T19:57:12.623536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 39202 -e production`
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543436+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:486:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543587+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543471+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:461:in `validate_runtime!'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543611+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543622+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.543599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-22T19:57:15.659621+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-22T19:57:15.642838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-22T19:57:43.446415+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=0244c6e7-7327-4607-af44-b97b982ca24a fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:43.744819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=f96b2b70-3c55-4fde-ac03-e365325598c4 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:44.991232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=08d2b9c8-bb56-4443-a505-6d8f3890e236 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:45.174088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=98bbb508-33c4-4bd3-8dfb-ed6acd9b1eca fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:45.887297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=df1b33a5-ec4e-41f0-89c8-12b147e2bfb6 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:46.053922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=6e39b8f9-4a4e-4141-9067-a32bf1621e9e fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:46.651470+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=51c63d7a-b98b-4cba-9f71-2368d46b78d7 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:46.825180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=82d1a487-6aa0-4710-b073-335664ff74b1 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:48.097023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=73611bae-7d9d-46e1-b921-e030d9868cd3 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:48.336866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=8fe9f620-c154-4c60-bb3d-6292d9df5f6c fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:49.745128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=c3e5b9df-0cef-41a8-82ed-02fe945dd1c3 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T19:57:49.908798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=02162725-4a2c-4a38-9ccc-bec24d9fcfe6 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T20:00:50.654740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=10a16eeb-841b-4a35-a34b-ea8cd1060e9c fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T20:00:51.014613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=dd93bced-52ba-4064-a856-a3bdbce5119f fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T20:05:38.672583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=03dea5ff-c62a-43b0-a6cc-37b4adc844e7 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-22T20:05:38.981499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-headland-25042.herokuapp.com request_id=d8e2b616-c2b4-4614-8ccd-c83d6b3a88f3 fwd="208.94.109.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

edit 2: 
`ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]`

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Declare Ruby version
ruby '2.4.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use pg as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# USE bootstrap-sass
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'


# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# UnicodeUtils implements Unicode algorithms for case conversion, normalization, text segmentation and more in pure Ruby code.
gem 'unicode_utils', '~> 1.4.0'

#Select2
gem 'select2-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

#Chart.js for Rails Version 2.0.2
gem 'chart-js-rails', '~> 0.1.0'

#progress bar
gem 'nprogress-rails'

gem 'responders', '~> 2.4.0'

#paginate
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  #Heroku integration has previously relied on using the Rails plugin system, which has been removed from Rails 4. To enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku please add this
  gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.8)
      actionpack (= 4.2.8)
      actionview (= 4.2.8)
      activejob (= 4.2.8)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.8)
      actionview (= 4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.8)
      activemodel (= 4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.4)
    autoprefixer-rails (7.1.6)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.3)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.1.0)
    chart-js-rails (0.1.4)
      railties (> 3.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.6)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.10.3)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    nokogiri (1.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    nprogress-rails (0.2.0.2)
    pg (0.21.0)
    rack (1.6.8)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.8)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.8)
      actionpack (= 4.2.8)
      actionview (= 4.2.8)
      activejob (= 4.2.8)
      activemodel (= 4.2.8)
      activerecord (= 4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.8)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.8)
      actionpack (= 4.2.8)
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    sass (3.5.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    select2-rails (4.0.3)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode_utils (1.4.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.5)
  byebug
  chart-js-rails (~> 0.1.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  nprogress-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.8)
  rails_12factor
  responders (~> 2.4.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.6)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  select2-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicode_utils (~> 1.4.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.4.2p198

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.2
```

Comment: I'm confused. I see warnings, but no error. And it ends with `deployed to Heroku`. So, what's the error?

Comment: When I open the app: "Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." The above build log is all I got.

Comment: You should be able to do something like: `heroku logs` in your console and see what the errors are in heroku. Depending on how you have things configured, you may need to add the `--remote` directive. You can also add `--tail` to see what's happening on heroku in real time.

Comment: `heroku logs` gives this error: `ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443`

Comment: Okay, well, here's the deal. It's pretty clear that the problem has *nothing* to do with "Restore Ruby gems after OS High Sierra upgrade". There are two paths I would suggest. First, in `config/environments/development.rb`, you could change `config.eager_load = false` to `config.eager_load = true` and see if you can replicate your system failure on server restart. Second, you need to learn/figure out how to connect to heroku (that error you're getting, `ENOTFOUND`, etc., suggests a whole different problem).

Comment: `ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443` error is now gone and a whole set of logs shown if I run `heroku logs`. I am really new to rails and heroku and might be missing something.

Comment: Please add to your question: (1) what you get when you do `ruby -v` in your console, and (2) your `Gemfile`.

Comment: @jvillian I've looked everywhere but still can't find the cause... thanks for your help.

Comment: @sampbay, walk me through this please. You had a RoR app live on Heroku when you upgraded to High Sierra, correct?